# Dojo 1.7 require not defined error

Tags: dojo

am trying to replace Dojo 1.6 data grid with d grid in Dojo 1.7.I installed corresponding Dojo1.7 files.But am getting error require not defined error while executing code.

Comment: Can you post your code ?

Comment: And the error message from Firebug

Answer (score 0):

I had that problem and I found that I was not actually using Dojo 1.7. When I installed Dojo 1.7.1, the "require not defined" error went away.

Answer (score 0):

Replace all require statements to import statements. Example:

```
 //BEFORE:
    const Web3 = require('web3');
    //AFTER:
    import Web3 from 'web3';
```